# Upgrading EF in pregenerated views: The default target Entity Framework version requires the edmx schema version 2 or lower

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, t4, ef-model-first

I have pre-generated views following the **templates** of the next link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx

I need to improve to Entity Framework 5.0 but if I replace the schemas as following:

> stringBuilder.Replace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs"); 
>   stringBuilder.Replace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"); 
>   stringBuilder.Replace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx","http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx"); 
>   stringBuilder.Replace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl");

I still having the following error:

> Warning   3   The default target Entity Framework version requires the
>   edmx schema version 2.0.0.0 or lower. The specified schema is version
>   3.0.0.0. To avoid this warning specify the target Entity Framework version explicitly. You can do this by using the EdmGen.exe
>   command-line tool with the targetVersion option, or by including the
>   targetEntityFrameworkVersion parameter when calling the GenerateCode
>   method.

Any idea of how to solve this issue **using templates**?

What is the equivalent of adding /targetversion:4.5 to EdmGen **using templates**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem...

There was a leading help in the following link:

http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/05/28/entity-framework-code-first-and-pre-generated-views/

> moozzyk says:
> August 5, 2012 at 11:51 pm
>
> I did see this when using Visual Studio 2012 and EF5. For now the workaround is to edit the >template. Change the line 70 from:
> var errors = viewGenerator.GenerateViews(mappingItemCollection, writer).ToList();
> to:
> var errors = viewGenerator.GenerateViews(mappingItemCollection, writer, >**EntityFrameworkVersions.Version3**).ToList();
> Sorry for the inconvenience.

I had to slighlty modify my code in a similar way, from:

> IList errors = viewGenerator.GenerateViews(mappingItems, writer);

To:

> IList errors = viewGenerator.GenerateViews(mappingItems, writer, **EntityFrameworkVersions.Version3**);

After that, no warning nor error whatsoever.